# MySQL single query to determine matched records and percentage for test/answers

Tags: mysql

Existing doctors test system (multiple choice), has a table of doctors, a table of tests, a table of questions and a table of answers (4 per question) and lastly, a table of answers that the doctor supplied.

Schema is as such:

`doctors` Table

```
id   |initials|
1661 |AP
```

`tests` Table

```
id |test   |released  |expires   
141|Example|2009-02-21|2010-03-01
```

`test_questions` Table (eg: correct answer for test_question.id 3417 is test_answers.id=5249)

```
id  |test_id|question             |test_answer_id
3417|141    |1. Example Question? |5249
3418|141    |2. Example Question? |5252
3419|141    |3. Example Question? |5254
3420|141    |4. Example Question? |5261
3421|141    |5. Example Question? |5262
3422|141    |6. Example Question? |5269
3423|141    |7. Example Question? |5273
3424|141    |8. Example Question? |5275
3425|141    |9. Example Question? |5279
3426|141    |10. Example Question?|5285
```

`test_answers` Table (Truncated for example)

```
id|test_question_id|answer
5249|3417| (d) It depends d
5248|3417| (c) depends c
5247|3417| (b) It depends b
5246|3417| (a) depends
```

`doctor_test_answers` Table (This is the doctors selected answers for each question)

```
id    |doctor_id|test_id|test_question_id|test_answer_id
189981|1661     |141    |3417            |5248
189982|1661     |141    |3418            |5252
189983|1661     |141    |3419            |5254
189984|1661     |141    |3420            |5261
189985|1661     |141    |3421            |5262
189986|1661     |141    |3422            |5269
189987|1661     |141    |3423            |5273
189988|1661     |141    |3424            |5275
189989|1661     |141    |3425            |5279
189990|1661     |141    |3426            |5285
```

As you can see from the above, in this case, the doctor answered test_question_id 3417 incorrectly (test_answer_id 5248 instead of 5249 and so should get 90% as a result for the test)

Using pure SQL (no procedures/functions), how can I construct a query that would result in a list of tests a doctor has taken and their percentage for said test

Desired result set:

```
doctor_id|initials|test_id|test   |result
1661     |AP      |141    |Example|90%
```

I'm currently using multiple queries by first selecting all tests a doctor has written then programatically looping through the answers of each one to check the result.
I'd like this in a single query instead...

Comment: The id is PRIMARY (e.g. 3417), so there's no point storing 141 in the doctors_test_answers table.

Comment: Yes, I would of done this all different was I starting from a clean slate - but this is what I have to work with as I am making alterations to an existing system :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeng as we have a (redundant) test_id column, we may as well use it...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS doctors_test_answers;

CREATE TABLE doctors_test_answers
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,doctor_id INT NOT NULL
,test_id INT NOT NULL
,test_question_id INT NOT NULL
,test_answer_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO doctors_test_answers VALUES
(189981,1661,141,3417,5248),
(189982,1661,141,3418,5252),
(189983,1661,141,3419,5254),
(189984,1661,141,3420,5261),
(189985,1661,141,3421,5262),
(189986,1661,141,3422,5269),
(189987,1661,141,3423,5273),
(189988,1661,141,3424,5275),
(189989,1661,141,3425,5279),
(189990,1661,141,3426,5285);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_questions;

CREATE TABLE test_questions
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,test_id INT NOT NULL
,question_no TINYINT NOT NULL
,question_text VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
,correct_answer_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_questions VALUES
(3417,141, 1,'Example Question?',5249),
(3418,141, 2,'Example Question?',5252),
(3419,141, 3,'Example Question?',5254),
(3420,141, 4,'Example Question?',5261),
(3421,141, 5,'Example Question?',5262),
(3422,141, 6,'Example Question?',5269),
(3423,141, 7,'Example Question?',5273),
(3424,141, 8,'Example Question?',5275),
(3425,141, 9,'Example Question?',5279),
(3426,141,10,'Example Question?',5285);

SELECT a.doctor_id
     , a.test_id
     , SUM(q.correct_answer_id IS NOT NULL)/COUNT(*) pct 
  FROM doctors_test_answers a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN test_questions q 
    ON q.id = a.test_question_id 
   AND q.correct_answer_id = a.test_answer_id 
 GROUP 
    BY doctor_id
     , test_id;
+-----------+---------+--------+
| doctor_id | test_id | pct    |
+-----------+---------+--------+
|      1661 |     141 | 0.9000 |
+-----------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: thanks - you renamed a table and a column, but the logic is there - thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, there's always a need to preserve one's sanity when addressing these things

Answer (score 1):

I can provide next solution:

```
select 
    da.doctor_id,
    d.initials,
    da.test_id,
    round(count(tq.test_answer_id)/count(test_question_id) * 100) result
from doctor_test_answers da
join doctors d on d.id = da.doctor_id
left join test_questions tq 
    on da.test_question_id = tq.id and da.test_answer_id = tq.test_answer_id
group by doctor_id, test_id, d.initials
;
```

Fiddle: [SQLize.onine](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=35c552afb24a2bd46f4b16c600706e2c&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Result:

```
+===========+==========+=========+========+
| doctor_id | initials | test_id | result |
+===========+==========+=========+========+
| 1661      | AP       | 141     | 90     |
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+
```